# How to shutdown a java executor service only if all threads throw an exception

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using the below code in  a java application.It spawns 3 worker threads. What I need is that if one thread fails (throws an unhandled exception from run)other threads should continue execution. If I call executor.shutdown() as below it is terminating the other threads(no new tasks are accepted).One of the options that I was thinking was  to have a counter on the ExecutionException catch block and call shutdown only when counter==numConsumers. Is there a better way to do this?

```
    public void execute()  {
                  int numConsumers = Integer.parseInt(configs.getSINK_NUMBER_OF_CONSUMERs());
Future<?> future=null;
                  log.info("Creating {}  consumers",numConsumers);
                  List<String> topics = Arrays.asList(configs.getTOPIC_NAME());
                  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numConsumers);
                  final List<SinkConsumer> consumers = new ArrayList<>();
                  for (int i = 0; i < numConsumers; i++) {
                    consumer = new SinkConsumer(UUID.randomUUID().toString(),topics,configs);
                    consumers.add(consumer);
                    future =  executor.submit(consumer);
                  }
            try {
                         future.get();
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                     } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                         executor.shutdown();
                     }
            }
```

Comment: Sure, you could compare a global variable and counter when a thread throws an exception, or you could also set an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` for each thread that could check for that condition, though I'm not 100% sure it would work

Comment: The [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) is an abstraction, designed to decouple task execution from technicalities like thread management. Your desired behaviour, however, needs explicit thread management. Maybe you want to switch to a different solution?

Comment: @Turing85  - This is working in cases where all threads fail or if  you just have one worker thread .If I do not call  shutdown  the issue is that application will not die  even if  all the threads are done.Thinking in your lines I  will read more ,I guess you are suggesting to create my own thread pool implementation

Comment: I do not think that a task pool is the right way to go here. In a task pool,mapping tasks to threads should be transparent to the user. Furthermore, in a typical task pool scenario, the number of tasks is significant larger than the number of threads. From your description, however, it seems like you have an (almost) equal amount of threads and tasks.

Comment: Why do you use multithreading in 'a single thread mode' ? The problem is that future.get(); will wait until the first Thread will be done and only after that the second thread will be submited. So each time only one thread will be executed. This is strange solution, and it does not make any sens to use mutithreaing at all.

Comment: @mger1979  You are right . . I would have to have that get  after I submit multiple tasks